How to create a bar chart image on nodejs without a browser?
Have a single nodejs project using a PDF generator, and need paste a bar chart into it, but the project runs on a desktopless server.
Have any library or method to create a bar chart image on nodejs on the runtime without a web browser for paste it into a pdf file?
I use puppeteer for create the PDF but the Chart.js library can not render the canvas, by example:
await page.setContent(`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
<script>
    const ctx = document.getElementById('chart');

    new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: { y: { beginAtZero: true } }
        }
    });
</script>
</body></html>`,
{ waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });

await page.addScriptTag({ url: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js' })

The results is a blank page. That's why I'm looking for a better option to generate a simple image and paste it directly.
I also tried:
await page.setContent(`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</body></html>`,
{ waitUntil: [ 'load', 'networkidle0' ] });

await page.addScriptTag({ url: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js' });
await page.addScriptTag({ content: `
    const ctx = document.getElementById('chart');

    new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: { y: { beginAtZero: true } }
        }
    });
});


You need to add the script tag, then set the page content. Otherwise, you're trying to run chart.js before it's been loaded. See Puppeteer with Chart.js

Thanks, i change the wait for waitUntil: ["load","networkidle0"] and move the script tag to page.addScriptTag to end of cdn url but does not work.

Did you try running the exact code in my answer? Let me know if that works for you. There's no point in ["load", "networkidle0"] because "load" will always happen before "networkidle0".

I update the question with the changes.

Your update invalidated my answer a bit, so I'll probably need to roll it back. Can you let me know whether my answer works for you or not? Please run the exact code verbatim and confirm that test.png was written. Your second attempt makes more sense but I'd just do the whole thing in one setContent call as shown--if that doesn't work, then I'll look into troubleshooting your second attempt.

You're adding the script after running the chart.js code that depends on it. Try adding the script first:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.6.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
<script>
    const ctx = document.getElementById('chart');
    new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: { y: { beginAtZero: true } },
            animation: { duration: 0 },
        }
    });
</script>
</body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.pdf({path: "test.pdf"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

Note that I'm also disabling animations so the screenshot captures the final chart rather than an in-progress rendering of it. If you still see missing pieces, you can wait until requests arrive or use a broader (less optimal) approach like setContent(html, {waitUntil: "networkidle0"}).
When things seem to be "not showing up" (or whatever) in web projects, be sure to look at the developer tools to see if there are JS errors. Your original code should give Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined which is a pretty clear description of the issue.
Contrary to your original post title, we are using a browser here, it's just running headlessly. It's useful to open it headfully for temporary debugging with puppeteer.launch({headless: false}).
See also:

Puppeteer with Chart.js
Sending a PDF as an Express response

